# Slim Framework : Homepage Routing without Trailing Slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, slim

Using Slim 3, I want my homepage URL to be `www.domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com/`.

This routing will redirect all home request to `www.domain.com/`

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {

});
```

But this one gives me error.

```
$app->get('', function ($request, $response, $args) {

});
```

I'm using standard .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I think this is a common issue. What is the best workaround for this?

**Edit:**

What is the trick or workaround so that the homepage url looked like it is without trailing slash on the address bar?

Comment: This is not a common issue. The first trailing slash after the domain is *always* required, and the resulting request is always identical.

Comment: There are lots of websites, their homepage are not using the trailing slash. StackOverflow itself is one of the example.

Comment: No, your browser may choose to not show it, but it is there. It is *always* the first character of the Request URI. It is not part of the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `/` is required by the HTTP spec. If you go to https://stackoverflow.com in Firefox and inspect the headers actually sent using LiveHTTPHeaders, you see this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: prov=6c390324-a9bb-439b-872e-ab428c1c136d; __cfduid=dd9fcf26e8242833656cda6fbe7719d851450684069; _ga=GA1.2.1110081223.1450684070
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see from the request line (`GET / HTTP/1.1`), the initial `/` is automatically added for you by the browser as specified in section 5.2.1 of [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2) where it says:

*Note that the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the original URI, it MUST be given as "/" (the server root).*